# I can't control VideoView buttons

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I want my VideoView to do something else than starting the video.
How can I do that?

I tried to put the method I want to do anywhere in the code, but I couldn't make it work.
Can you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can check,

```
protected Runnable playingCheck = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
              if(videoview.getCurrentPosition() > 0){
                   // Do ypur stuff
              }  
            }
        }
    };
```

Then call,

```
playingCheck.start();
```